# Lightning related list custom buttons not showing

Tags: lightning, custom-button, url

I have a custom URL button on the related list of OpportunityLineItem, in classic it works perfectly fine and my list only shows the custom buttom alone, which is what i want. But in Lightning it does not show, and it was showing and working until this weekend's release got out. Now on this related list only shows the edit and delete buttons and they are greyed out. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I've encountered similar issues and was wondering if you were able to find a fix.

Comment: eventually it fixed itself. im guessing it has to do with the version deployed currently on the instance's server.